# Manifold based on Grassmann numbers?

Tags: manifolds

A manifold is locally homoeomorphic to Euclidean space. Is there a notion of a manifold that has Grassmann coordinates instead of Euclidean coordinates?

Comment: What do you mean by Grassmann coordinates?

Comment: If by Grassmann coordinates you mean anti-commuting coordinate functions, then yes - they are locally ringed spaces called supermanifolds.

Comment: @QuaereVerum That's what I was looking for, cheers